# In a helper function, is there a way to reference the component that invoked it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, helper

I am new to Salesforce development, so please excuse me if this is an obvious question.

I've developed a number of helper functions for my lightning component. For some of those functions, I need the component value in order to invoke an Apex function that is defined in my aura:component controller. Is there a way for me to look up the calling component that ultimately invoked the helper function or do I need to pass the component parameter down through the levels?

Comment: Hello Eric G, could you please clarify your question a bit more? I actually couldn't understand it. Do you mean passing data from Aura Component via JS to the Apex or something like that?

Comment: You have to pass the component to the helper function.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @CyberJus -- that's what it looked like (I need to pass the component). I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some way to find the component without passing it.

Comment: The helper is a singleton, there is just one instance of the helper for all of the components of that type, that is why it needs the component passed to it.

Answer (score 0):

controller.js

```
({
   doSth: function(component, event, helper) {
          helper.helperFunction(component, event, helper);
   }
})
```

helper.js

```
({
    helperFunction: function(component, event, helper) {
        // component  <-- this is your reference
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you - that is what I am doing. I was hoping I didn't need to pass it in to all my helper functions, but I can continue to do that.